# ASP.NET razor: Form not submitting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

Since I added a DisplayFormat and datepicker to my DateTime properties/inputfields, my form stopped submitting. I don't get any errors (In chrome F12 or Visual studio).

Edit: I've set Displayformat to dd/MM/yyyy and the datepicker to "dd/mm/yyyy". But that didn't solve it either.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCampaign", "Home")) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Campaign</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Campaign.CampaignName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Campaign.CampaignName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campaign.CampaignName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Campaign.WebsiteUrl)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Campaign.WebsiteUrl)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campaign.WebsiteUrl)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Campaign.PrivacyPolicyUrl)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Campaign.PrivacyPolicyUrl)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campaign.PrivacyPolicyUrl)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Campaign.TermsUrl)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Campaign.TermsUrl)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campaign.TermsUrl)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Campaign.PricepageUrl)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Campaign.PricepageUrl)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campaign.PricepageUrl)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Campaign.Startdate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Campaign.Startdate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campaign.Startdate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Campaign.Enddate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Campaign.Enddate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campaign.Enddate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Campaign.Starthour)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Campaign.Starthour, new SelectList(Model.Hours))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campaign.Starthour)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Campaign.Endhour)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Campaign.Endhour, new SelectList(Model.Hours))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campaign.Endhour)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Campaign.PMAM)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Campaign.PMAM, new SelectList(Model.AMPM, "key", "value"))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campaign.PMAM)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Campaign.Language)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Campaign.Language, new SelectList(Model.Languages, "key", "value"))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campaign.Language)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Campaign.FK_ID_MerchantApp)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Campaign.FK_ID_MerchantApp)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campaign.FK_ID_MerchantApp)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Campaign.CampaignType)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Campaign.CampaignType, new SelectList(Model.Types, "key", "value"))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campaign.CampaignType)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Campaign_Startdate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
        minDate: new Date()
    });
    $('#Campaign_Enddate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
        minDate: new Date()
    });

</script>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>




       public class Campaign
        {
            #region CTor
            public Campaign()
            {
            }
            #endregion

            #region Properties

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id_campaign")]
            public string ID_Campaign { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Campaignname")]
            public string CampaignName { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Websiteurl")]
            public string WebsiteUrl { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Privacypolicyurl")]
            public string PrivacyPolicyUrl { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Termsurl")]
            public string TermsUrl { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Pricepageurl")]
            public string PricepageUrl { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Maxcredit")]
            public Int32 MaxCredit { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fk_id_currency")]
            public string FK_ID_Currency { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Maxscans")]
            public short MaxScans { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Startdate")]
            [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}")]
            public DateTime Startdate { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Enddate")]
            [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}")]
            public DateTime Enddate { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Starthour")]
            public short Starthour { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Endhour")]
            public short Endhour { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Pmam")]
            public string PMAM { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Language")]
            public string Language { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fk_id_merchantapp")]
            public string FK_ID_MerchantApp { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Campaigntype")]
            public string CampaignType { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Createtimestamp")]
            [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}")]
            public DateTime CreateTimestamp { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Lastupdate")]
            [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}")]
            public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Lastupdateby")]
            public string LastUpdateBy { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Status")]
            public short Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: when you say it's 'not submitting' - do you mean the browser isn't sending it (in which case it's a markup issue)?  Or that the data isn't being read correctly on the server?

Comment: When I click on the "Submit" button, nothing happens. Don't think it's a markup issue else chrome F12 would've complaint about it.

Comment: And I didn't have this problem until I added the DateFormat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you have validation summary set to true.  Could it be that unobtrusive validation is preventing your form from being submitted and you cant see it because the error isn't attached to a specific field?  Maybe, try to set it to false, and see if anything pops up?  Do you have [unobtrusive validation turned on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg618489) along with client validation?

Did you use chrome's network tool to check if any http post's are being sent out upon submission?  Have you tried using the "dd/mm/yyyy" in your model as well?

Comment: Shoot me please. Thanks for fixing. The datepicker isn't working atm but i'll figure out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a form. Wrap it in Html.BeginForm:

```
 @{ using (Html.BeginForm()) { 




              ....




    }
 }
```

Comment: There is, just didn't copy it into my question, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It might sound too obvious, but since it stopped working after you added the 'datepicker', and you are using jQuery, you should try adding

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

to wrap your 'datepicker' code.

Comment: I've just removed everything that has to do with the datepicker and DisplayFormat and my form still doesn't submit.
Thanks for the tip though.